# $S=\{\sin\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ what can we say about openess, closedness, boundedness.

Tags: real-analysis

The set **is not open since domain is** $\mathbb N$

**it is bounded** since $-1\le \sin x\le 1$

But for closedness I want to say something about sequential characterization, but I cannot do it as follows:

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. A set $F\subset X$ is closed if and only if for every sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}\subset F$, if $x\in X$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$ then $x\in F$.

Take any $\{x_n\}$ in $S$ so $\{x_n\}$'s elements are in the form of $\sin 1/n$
There is no other way to convergence but $0$ since $\lim\sin1/n=0$

Is it true? about sequential part? and How to do it properly?

Comment: what's your question

Comment: $S$ is closed iff $0\in S$. Is it true that $0\in S$?

Comment: no $0$ is limit but not in S so S is not closed too

Comment: But do you know how to justify that domain = N $\implies$ not open?

Comment: Then what can we say about $S\cup \{0\}$

Comment: @Ovi: For given any ball centered at $sin1/n$ for some $n$ I can find elements from the $R$ so it is not open.

Comment: @user2312512851 Ok. An easier way would be to say that if it's open it must contain a ball; but balls are uncoutable and $S$ is only countable.

Answer (score 7):

It is not closed since it doesn't contain $0$ as one of its limit points; which can be converged to by the following sequence $$a_n=\sin{1\over n}$$